# After submit comments select the current tab

Tags: comments

In my `single.php` I have 3 tabs one for description, others for comments and reviews my question is when I submit the comments, the first tab is always selected. My code:

```
            <div id="product-information">
                <div id="tabs" class="htabs">
                    <a href="#tab-description" class="selected">Description</a> 
                    <a href="#tab-comment" class="">Comments</a>
                    <a href="#tab-review" class="">Reviews</a> 
                </div>

                <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>          
                </div>

                <div id="tab-comment" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
                    <?php if ( comments_open() || true): ?>
                        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>

                 <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
                    <h1>REVIEW</h1>
                </div>

             </div>
```

How can I pass the attribute `class="selected"` dynamically?

Comment: This question likely is not specific to WordPress and hence out of [scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Regardless, there's got to be some javascript that goes with this. You'd have to post that as well.

Comment: I d'not see the usefulness of javascript here, because the problem is after sending th comments form, otherwise i manage well the change of the tabs in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best solution is to add an get attribute, in this case we don't need javascript like this:
your single.php :

```
            <div id="product-information">
            <div id="tabs" class="htabs">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&tab=description" class="<?php echo !isset($_GET['tab']) || ($_GET['tab'] == 'description') ? 'selected':''; ?>">Description</a> 
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&tab=comment" class="<?php echo isset($_GET['tab']) && ($_GET['tab'] == 'comment') ? 'selected':''; ?>">Comments</a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&tab=review" class="<?php echo isset($_GET['tab']) && ($_GET['tab'] == 'review') ? 'selected':''; ?>">Reviews</a> 
            </div>

            <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" style="display: <?php echo !isset($_GET['tab']) || ($_GET['tab'] == 'description') ? 'block;':'none;'; ?>">
                <?php the_content(); ?>          
            </div>

            <div id="tab-comment" class="tab-content" style="display: <?php echo isset($_GET['tab']) && ($_GET['tab'] == 'comment') ? 'block;':'none;'; ?>">
                <?php if ( comments_open() || true): ?>
                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>

             <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content" style="display: <?php echo isset($_GET['tab']) && ($_GET['tab'] == 'review') ? 'block;':'none;'; ?>;">
                <h1>REVIEW</h1>
            </div>

         </div>
```

and in your function.php add this:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'redirect_after_comment' ) ) {
function redirect_after_comment($location)
{
    return get_permalink().'&tab=comment';
}
   }
   add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
```